# FOR XML PATH SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, for-xml-path

I am trying to write a query on SQL Server, I can but not exactly what I want so I need help

```sql
SELECT (
    select top 1 (
        SELECT top 1 
            (select LTRIM(RTRIM(posta_kodu)) vdKodu from per_bol_tanimlari),
            donem = 'aylik',
            yil = 2020,
            ay = 7
        FROM per_bol_tanimlari
        WHERE posta_kodu is not null
        FOR XML PATH('donem'), root('idari'), TYPE
    ),
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.vergi_no)) AS mukellif_vergi_no,
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.resmi_unvani)) AS soyadi,
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.sicil_no)) AS tcKimlikNo,
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.telefon1)) AS telNo
FROM dbo.per_bol_tanimlari pbt
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('genel'), TYPE
```

and the result is like

```xml
<genel>
  <idari>
    <donem>
      <vdKodu>11111</vdKodu>
      <donem>aylik</donem>
      <yil>2020</yil>
      <ay>7</ay>
    </donem>
  </idari>
.........
</genel>
```

But I need

```xml
<genel>
  <idari>
    <vdKodu>11111</vdKodu>
    <donem>
      <donem>aylik</donem>
      <yil>2020</yil>
      <ay>7</ay>
    </donem>
  </idari>
.....
</genel>
```

I've tried a lot of things but I can't

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of `TOP 1`s and no `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0):

test this one:

```
SELECT (
    select top 1  (select LTRIM(RTRIM(posta_kodu)) vdKodu from per_bol_tanimlari),(
        SELECT top 1 
           
            donem = 'aylik',
            yil = 2020,
            ay = 7
        FROM per_bol_tanimlari
        WHERE posta_kodu is not null
        FOR XML PATH('donem'), root('idari'), TYPE
    ),
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.vergi_no)) AS mukellif_vergi_no,
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.resmi_unvani)) AS soyadi,
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.sicil_no)) AS tcKimlikNo,
    Ltrim(Rtrim(pbt.telefon1)) AS telNo
FROM dbo.per_bol_tanimlari pbt
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('genel'), TYPE
```

Comment: Its not working like this but i did thanks any way :)